# Asp.NET dropdown inside dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dropdown

When clicking on an hyperlink, I create a dialog containing a dropdown (list of user) and a button. When clicking on the button, I need to retrieve the selected user.

The problem is that I can't add `AutoPostBack = true` on the dropdown because it will make the popup dialog disapear.

**POPUP CODE**

```
<div runat="server" id="LogonAsPopup" style="display: none;">
    <div class="form">
        <div class="field" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;">
            <ab:LabelledDropDownlist runat="server" ID="ddlUsers" DataTextField="Username" DataValueField="UserID" DataSourceID="dsUsers" Width="200px" />
            <br/>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btLogOn" OnClick="btLogOn_OnClick" style="margin-top: 10px;" UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>                    
        </div>
    </div>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="dsUsers" TypeName="Business.UserManager"
        SelectMethod="GetEnabledUsersList">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
</div>
```

**ON CLICK**

```
protected void btLogOn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectedUserId = Int32.Parse(ddlUsers.SelectedValue);
}
```

**HYPERLINK NAVIGATE URL**

```
hl.NavigateUrl = "javascript: $('#LogonAsPopup').show(); $('#LogonAsPopup').dialog({title: '" + (String)GetGlobalResourceObject("Labels","LogonAsTitle") + "', width: 500, modal: true});";
```

How can I retrieve the selected item ?

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the inline `style="display: none;"` and instead put in the `Page_Load()` put

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    LogonAsPopup.Attributes.Add("style","display:none");
}
```

This will set the display attribute to `none`, but only when the page first loads.  Now the `AutoPostBack` will work as wanted

Comment: Have I to add "AutoPostBack = true' on my dropdown ?

Comment: This doesnt work.. I tried with and without the postback on dropdown

Comment: Yes.  This just stops the PostBack hiding the popup

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger the dialog to show again on the `_SelectedIndexChanged` event of the dropdown list. This is what I use:

```
protected void ***_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:FunctionGoesHere();", true);
}
```